# Format time counter string e.g. 260 to 00:00:00 in android

Tags: java, android, string, date, time

I am working on a simple timer like:

```
timer.schedule(new timerTask(), 100, 100);  

// Timer
public class timerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (stop==false){
            tcount=tcount+1;
        }
    }
};
```

The result is a string e.g. 260 that means 260 second is spent
So are there any way to convert it to 00:00:00 (performance is a concern as convert run frequentlly!)

So is the approach 260/60/60 = hr etc... the most appropriate one? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date(260 * 1000); //260000 milliseconds

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

String result = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: Although it's _nice-and-easy_, doesn't it lag behind a bit on performance?

Comment: I used this way many times, I didn't saw any perfomance issues.

Comment: Is it okay for a tight loop? quote : ***performance is a concern as convert run frequentlly!***

Comment: I use this way to show date in ListView adapter, it scrolls without freezes if I scroll fast. Even in old devices like LG P500.

Comment: Besides performance, I have a problem becuase it show 08:00:00 by default, I suspect the problem is due to GCT+ 8 , how to fix this? thanks

Comment: should i set the gmt to 0?

Comment: You can use Locale.ENGLISH in SimpleDateFormat constructor: new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: it is still 08:00:00 by default

Comment: TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0");
  sdf.setTimeZone(zone); fixed the problem

Comment: OK, sorry that I cant help you with it.